# Override BackButton while focus is on "input text box"

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to override backbutton in a phonegap application. but it is not working when input text box is in focus . it is exiting the app instead of the overridden behaviour . i am using 
    document.addEventListener("backbutton",backbuttonTap,false);
way to handle backbutton where backbuttonTap is the function . and while i am in the same page which contains input textbox, the overridden behaviour is working

Answer (score 1):

Can you include  backbuttonTap function's code? because I had no idea what you trying to do. but as a general answer I woill put a backbutton functionality I implemented.

```
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    if ($.mobile.activePage[0].id == "home"
        || $.mobile.activePage[0].id == "login") {
        e.preventDefault();
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }else if($.mobile.activePage[0].id == "inspection"){
        e.preventDefault();
        back();
        //return false;
    }else if($.mobile.activePage[0].id == "noDetails"){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.mobile.changePage("home.html");
        return false;
    }else{
        navigator.app.backHistory();
    }

}
```

Comment: i exactly did the same thing . but in my case say a page with nodetails as id has a text input box, i click on it and then onscreen keyboard pops up , now if u press back twice ( one time to remove onscreen keyboard )it has to go to home page but instead it is exiting the application

Comment: that's interesting. because I have some text fields in inspection page. but it doesn't give show any behavior as yours.(mind back() function has $.mobile.changePage("home.html") in it.) Is there any errors in the Logcat?